# How can execute specific Thread Group in Jmeter with command?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to run any specific Thread Group with Command in windows. I have tried with using properties file but got failed. Now need help for executing any specific thread group selecting from command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool. It is a wrapper around JMeter (and several other performance testing tools) which provides an easy way of configure (or create) and run a JMeter test using simple [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) syntax.

For instance if you need to disable `Thread Group B` the relevant configuration would be something like:

```
---
execution:
  scenario:
    script: test.jmx
    modifications:
      disable:  # Names of the tree elements to disable
      - Thread Group B
      enable:  # Names of the tree elements to enable
      - Thread Group A
```

References:

- [Modifications for Existing Scripts](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Answer (score 0):

If Thread group's `Number of Threads` is set to 0 it won't execute.

Based on that, you can set for each thread group `Number of Threads` with [__property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) with default 0 per group number, e.g. for Thread group 1:

```
${__property(group1,,0)}
```

so if you execute in command prompt `jmeter -Jgroup3=1 ...` - if you want only thread group 3 be executed with 1 thread/user (other groups will have 0 users and won't get executed)

[image]

Comment: properties file contains : Thread1.users=5
Thread2.users=0 and run  "jmeter -n -t KonaCard_Test_Script_02-03.jmx -l KonaCard_Test_Script_02-03.jtl -p configthread.properties"
and executed both thread but i just wanted to run thread-1. 


"so if you send -Jgroup3=1 - only group 3 will be execute with 1 thread/user" 

couldn't understand this statement. Could you please explain this one  in details?

Comment: I have tested following the below properties:  properties file name is configthread.properties and properties file contains: PurchaseReward.users=0
InfoChange.users=1               And used ${__configthread(InfoChange.users,,1)} in Number of Thread field in Jmeter . But execution failed.

Comment: there's no function `__configthread`, why are you doing different solution? try `${__property(InfoChange.users,,0)}`

Comment: I have used ${__property(InfoChange.users,,0)} and got error "No enabled thread groups found " in jmeter lof file :(

Comment: you need to add additional property file using `-q configthread.properties`

Comment: I have executed this command  "jmeter -n -t KonaCard_Test_Script_02-03.jmx -l KonaCard_Test_Script_02-03.jtl -p configthread.properties"

Comment: I have executed this command "jmeter -n -t KonaCard_Test_Script_02-03.jmx -l KonaCard_Test_Script_02-03.jtl -p configthread.properties" and got failed